# Javascript replace `sq-` or `sq.`

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'd like to do a replace on a string that contains `sq-` or `sq.` I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
var imgSrc = event.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
    imgSrc = imgSrc.replace('sq-', 'mt-') || imgSrc.replace('sq.', 'mt.');
```

Any ideas on how I can get this working?

Comment: Well, what did you try? Using a "*capture group*" and  "*back reference*" in the replacement value would be useful. (It can be solved with a "*lookbehind*" and using the entire-match as well..)

Comment: Thought I could use a native js method (`replace()`) instead of using a regex (in my example above)

Comment: Anyway, that code doesn't work because `||` is being used nonsensically (`||` evaluates to the *first* truthy operand, or the last operand: e.g. `"hello" || "world"` evaluates to `"hello"`). Consider this: `x.replace(..).replace(..)` as an alternative to the above approach without a regex.

Comment: @pst ah that's what I was trying to do. In terms of speed, would this be slower than alex's regex below? (I'm thinking yes since it's calling the same method twice).

Comment: See alex's anser. I forgot that `String.replace` needs a regular expression to be able to match more than one .. both approaches will be "fast enough"; micro-benchmark to your hearts content and don't forget the "slow" browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it with one regex...

```
imgSrc = imgSrc.replace(/sq([.-])/g, 'mt$1');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GHeLf/).

The character class will match a literal `.` (because it loses its special meaning in a character class) and a literal `-` (doesn't look like a range so it has no special meaning either).

The match is placed in capturing group `1`, which is referenced in the replacement with `$1`.

[Performance test between one regex and two](http://jsperf.com/one-regex-vs-two).

Comment: Interesting solution. Thanks. Is this more or less efficient than chaining 2 `replace()`s?

Comment: @bob_cobb http://jsperf.com will tell you (see my updated answer). I'd do it in one because it's clearer to me (and I don't have to worry about two lots of `g` flags, etc).

Comment: @Bergi That's different behaviour, however (it will replace the first instance of each only).

Comment: Yes, that's why it's faster (altough it solves the testcase with only one appearance correctly :-)